# Align different datetime from different data frames

Tags: r

I'm struggling to find a solution for aligning two columns from different data frames.I'm trying to merge these two data frames in order to get the same observation time for both data frames. I've tried a lot of solutions provided here,especially merge from zoo and xts, but most of them are not usable in my case. Some dummy code.

df1

```
 df1<- structure(list(datetime = structure(c(1073098800, 1073131200, 
    1073142000, 1073163600, 1073703600, 1073736000, 1073746800, 1073768400, 
    1073790000, 1073822400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
        value = c(NA, NA, NA, -12.7, -12.9, -7.9, -6.2, -14, -11.7, 
        NA)), .Names = c("datetime", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 
    10L), class = "data.frame")
```

df2

```
df2<-structure(list(datetime = structure(1:10, .Label = c("2004-01-03 03:00:00", 
"2004-01-03 12:00:00", "2004-01-03 15:00:00", "2004-01-03 21:00:00", 
"2004-01-04 03:00:00", "2004-01-04 12:00:00", "2004-01-04 15:00:00", 
"2004-01-04 21:00:00", "2004-01-05 03:00:00", "2004-01-05 12:00:00"
), class = "factor"), value = c(-1.7, -2.2, -2.5, -3.9, -5.5, 
-5.6, -6, -6.7, -7.8, -7.6)), .Names = c("datetime", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

And  I want to get something like this:

```
datetime    value   datetime    value
2004-01-03 03:00:00 NA      2004-01-03 03:00:00 -1.7
2004-01-03 12:00:00 NA      2004-01-03 12:00:00 -2.2
2004-01-03 15:00:00 NA      2004-01-03 15:00:00 -2.5
2004-01-03 21:00:00 -12.7   2004-01-03 21:00:00 -3.9
2004-01-10 03:00:00 -12.9   2004-01-04 03:00:00 -5.5
2004-01-10 12:00:00 -7.9    2004-01-04 12:00:00 -5.6
2004-01-10 15:00:00 -6.2    2004-01-04 15:00:00 -6
2004-01-10 21:00:00 -14     2004-01-04 21:00:00 -6.7
2004-01-11 03:00:00 -11.7   2004-01-05 03:00:00 -7.8
2004-01-11 12:00:00 NA      2004-01-05 12:00:00 -7.6
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that the original data frames have different number of records. This is the main issue of merging these data.

Later EDIT.
I found that join from plyr will do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert to zoo and at the same time ensure they are both POSIXct, then merge.  Optionally convert back to data.frame.

```
library(zoo)

z1 <- read.zoo(df1)
z2 <- read.zoo(df2, tz = "")

z <- merge(z1, z2)

fortify.zoo(z)
```